# Attoparsec: matching any of strings with common prefix

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

I am trying to parse a limited set of valid strings which have a common prefix with attoparsec. However, My attempts result in either a `Partial` result or a premature `Done`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Applicative
import qualified Data.Attoparsec.Text as PT

data Thing = Foobar | Foobaz | Foobarz

thingParser1 = PT.string "foobarz" *> return Foobarz
           <|> PT.string "foobaz" *> return Foobaz
           <|> PT.string "foobar" *> return Foobar

thingParser2 = PT.string "foobar" *> return Foobar
           <|> PT.string "foobaz" *> return Foobaz
           <|> PT.string "foobarz" *> return Foobarz
```

What I want is for "foobar" to result in `Foobar`, "foobarz" to result in `Foobarz` and "foobaz" to result in `Foobaz`. However

```
PT.parse thingParser1 "foobar"
```

results in a `PT.Partial` and

```
PT.parse thingParser2 "foobarz"
```

results in a `PT.Done "z" Foobar`.

Comment: There are errors in your code, you have to import Control.Applicative and add a pure before the constructors in your parser or use the <$ operator and you probably want to derive show for Thing.

Comment: You're right. I was a bit overzealous in making the example minimal. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see the order of alternatives matters in the parsec family of parser combinator libraries. It will first try the parser on the left and only continue with the parser on the right if that fails.

Another thing to notice is that your parsers don't require that the input ends after parsing. You can force that by using [`parseOnly`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.14.1/docs/Data-Attoparsec-Text.html#v:parseOnly) instead of `parse` to run the actual parser. Or you can use the [`maybeResult`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.14.1/docs/Data-Attoparsec-Text.html#v:maybeResult) or [`eitherResult`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.14.1/docs/Data-Attoparsec-Text.html#v:eitherResult) functions to convert the `Result` into a `Maybe` or `Either` respectively.

That solution will work for `thingParser1`, but `thingParser2` will still not work. This is because you need to have both the `string` parser and an [`endOfInput`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.14.1/docs/Data-Attoparsec-Text.html#v:endOfInput) under a single `try`, this would work:

```
thingParser3 = Foobar  <$ PT.string "foobar"  <* endOfInput
           <|> Foobaz  <$ PT.string "foobaz"  <* endOfInput
           <|> Foobarz <$ PT.string "foobarz" <* endOfInput
```

A slightly better approach is to do a quick look ahead to see if an `z` follows the `foobar`, you can do that like this:

```
thingParser4 = Foobar  <$ (do
                 PT.string "foobar"
                 c <- peekChar
                 guard (maybe True (/= 'z') c))
           <|> Foobaz  <$ PT.string "foobaz"
           <|> Foobarz <$ PT.string "foobarz"
```

But this backtracking also degrades the performance, so I would stick with the `thingParser1` implementation.

Comment: Attoparsec does backtrack by default.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson thanks, it does indeed backtrack alternatives by default, however, it does not do full backtracking. I would expect to be able to factor out the three `endOfInput`s in `thingParser3` into a single sequened operation to the right, but then the backtracking will not work properly anymore.

Comment: `thingParser1` with `parseOnly` does indeed fulfill my needs. Thanks!